# Hammerspoon: execute default right mouse button action on button up rather than button down

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

I'm using a Logitech mouse with MacOS, and from observation:

- the left button executes its action on release (button up) in many (but not all) cases
- the right button executes its action on press (button down) in all (?) cases

I'd like to make the right button (conditionally) execute the action on up instead of down. I'm not sure if this is possible. Further context:

I have a simple script (below) that allows me to hold the right button down and use the scroll wheel to adjust system volume. It works, but the default button action (e.g. a context menu in a browser) still gets executed when the button goes down. I'd like to **not** execute the action if the scroll wheel is fiddled with (thus I need to wait until the button is lifted to execute, or skip, the action). Is this possible? I'm guessing I'd need a very different approach than what I have below (this is just for reference in terms of what I'm currently doing).

```
local eventtap = require("hs.eventtap")

volume_control = eventtap.new({eventtap.event.types.scrollWheel}, function(event)
    if eventtap.checkMouseButtons()[2] then
        hs.eventtap.keyStroke({}, "escape", 0); -- Make the context menu disappear
        local vol = hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():volume()
        if (event:getProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1) < 0) then vol = vol + 2 end
        if (event:getProperty(hs.eventtap.event.properties.scrollWheelEventDeltaAxis1) > 0) then vol = vol - 2 end
        hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():setVolume(vol)
        hs.alert.closeAll()
        hs.alert.show(string.format("Volume: %3.0f%%", hs.audiodevice.defaultOutputDevice():volume()), {}, hs.screen.mainScreen(), 0.4)
        return true
    end
end):start()
```